# Default behaviour for implicit arguments

Tags: scala, implicit

Is it possible to express a default value for the implicit argument for a class?

```
class I[T](val t: T)

class A(i: I[Int])(implicit f: I[Int] => Int) {

    implicit object key extends(I[Int] => Int) {
      def apply(i: I[Int])= i.t
    } 

    def this() = this(new I(0))(key)
}
```

the code above gives "error: not found: value key"

Answer (score 3):

You cannot refer to members of a class within the constructor, because the class hasn't been constructed yet. i.e. `key` is a member of `A`, so you cannot refer to `key` within the class constructor. You can however use a default parameter as an anonymous function:

```
scala> class A(i: I[Int])(implicit f: I[Int] => Int = { i: I[Int] => i.t } )
defined class A

scala> new A(new I(2))
res1: A = A@29ba4338
```

*Or*, if you want to make it a little more clean, you can create a method in the companion object of `A`, and reference it.

```
case class A(i: I[Int])(implicit f: I[Int] => Int = A.key)

object A {
    def key(i: I[Int]): Int = i.t
}
```

Or even:

```
case class A(i: I[Int])(implicit f: I[Int] => Int) {
    def this() = this(new I(0))(A.key)
}

object A {
    def key(i: I[Int]): Int = i.t
}
```

Comment: It's clear to use such approach, but real case is more comlicated, I have  multiple constructors, is it possible to minimize the code copies.

Comment: @kokorins You can also put the function within the companion object of the class. That could keep it cleaner.